# Разбитие изображения на части и сохранение их

Tags: c#

Мне нужно брать изображения (spritesheet), и разбивать их на ровные части. допустим 1 картинка: 0,0,16,16; 2 картинка:16, 16, 32, 32; ну думаю понятно. Я что то не нашел как в си шарпе работать с png, по этому и задал вопрос. Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека, либо функция.

Comment: Какую платформу используете? Ну, там, WPF, WinForms или у вас веб... А так можно использовать метод [Bitmap.Clone](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.clone?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Alexander Petrov WinForms.